# SourceSafe sharing and branching

Tags: visual-sourcesafe, branch

So far I've only checked things out and back in to Source Safe but now I want to create a project for parallel development. That is, I want to Share and Branch the entire project.

I have been reading the Source Safe Help files on how to do this and although I think I am following the instructions, I end up with an empty folder.

Can someone enumerate the steps required to do this?  Do you start by creating a new project under the Source Safe root so you have something to Share the original project with?

Note: We have SourceSafe 6.0.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you get away from sourcesafe as quickly as possible!  Especially vss6 :-). Having said that you should not need to creat a new vss db. Rather in your vss db root you would have at the top level something like db/trunk, db/patch, db/testing, etc. Wher db is your vss project database and the trunk/patch/testing are folders representing each branch you want to create.

Comment: I can't get away from Source Safe; it's what we use here but I understand your warning. Having said that, can you enumerate the steps to accomplish what you went on to recommend? Can I just copy the folder? What about the vss links?